# Shape size in centimetre not consistent

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, adobe

I create a shape in Excel specifying certain dimensions:

```
With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 96, 30, 144, 60)
    .Height = Application.CentimetersToPoints(2)  '2cm height
    .Width = Application.CentimetersToPoints(4)   '4cm width
End With
```

I then print the sheet as a PDF document using Adobe PDF printer. (Excel sheet size and printer sheet size are both set to A4).

The problem is that the size of the shape on the PDF is not the same as what is in Excel. On the PDF the width and height are different.

What is causing this problem and how do I fix it?

**Edit:**

Shape in ***Excel***

[image]

Shape in ***PDF***, measured using Adobe Acrobat measuring tools

[image]

Many thanks!

Comment: Is the print output scaled to fit?

Comment: How do you measure the height and width in your pdf? Can you share a screenshot of that please (e.g. PDF-XChange Editor)

Comment: @SolarMike No, on Excel it's set to "No Scaling", and on the pdf printer settings it's at 100% scaling (which is same as No Scaling I assume)

Comment: @JulianG Question updated with screenshots. Adobe Acrobat has built in measuring tools, I've used that to measure